# Ref returns null, but it isn’t(null)?

Tags: reactjs

I’m trying to make a react video player.
Video gets loaded fine, when I press play, it gets played and so on.
Trouble occurs when I want to display duration of it.
I tried accessing it via ref. It gets video, but ref returns null? I’m console logging and in it, amongst other properties is duration.
Here’s an image of:
[image]

To add: I’m calling ref in `componentDidMount()` just to see if it’s being ‘catched’.
Here is the code:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class Show extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {

        super(props);
        this.state = {
            video: "",
            switch: false,
            remaining: null,
        };
        this.playPause = this.playPause.bind(this);
        this.videoRef = React.createRef();
        this.trackTime = this.trackTime.bind(this);
        this.volume = this.volume.bind(this);
        this.fullScreen = this.fullScreen.bind(this);

    }

    fullScreen(){

        let elem = this.videoRef.current;
        if (elem.requestFullscreen){
            elem.requestFullscreen();
          } 
          else if (elem.mozRequestFullScreen){ /* Firefox */
            elem.mozRequestFullScreen();
          } 
          else if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen){ /* Chrome, Safari & Opera */
            elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
          } 
          else if (elem.msRequestFullscreen){ /* IE/Edge */
            elem.msRequestFullscreen();
          }

    }

    volume(e){
        this.videoRef.current.volume = e.target.value/100;
    }

    trackTime(e){
        this.setState({
            remaining: e.target.duration - e.target.currentTime,
        });
    }

    playPause(){

        this.setState({
            switch: !this.state.switch
        });

        if(this.videoRef.current.paused){
            this.videoRef.current.play();
        }
        else{
            this.videoRef.current.pause();
        }

    }

    componentDidMount(){

        let token = document.querySelector("meta[name='csrf-token']").getAttribute("content");

        let urlId = window.location.href;
        let getaVideoIdId = urlId.lastIndexOf("/");
        let videoId = urlId.substring(getaVideoIdId+1, urlId.length);

        $.ajax({
            url: '/showAjax',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {_token: token , message: "bravo", videoId: videoId},
            dataType: 'JSON',
            success: (response) => { 
                console.log("success");
                //console.log(response);
                this.setState({
                    video: response.video,
                }); 

            },
            error: (response) => {
                console.log("error");
                console.log(response);
            }
        }); 
        console.log(this.videoRef);
        //this.videoRef.current.play();
    }

    render(){
        //console.log(this.state);

        let PlayPause = this.state.switch ? "fa fa-pause-circle" : "fa fa-play-circle";

        let minutes = Math.floor(this.state.remaining/60);
        minutes = (""+minutes).length===1 ? "0"+minutes : minutes;//Checks if mins are one digit by turning it into string that now beasues length, if length is 1(single digit), if it is, then adds zero in front of it.
        let seconds = Math.floor(this.state.remaining%60);
        seconds = (""+seconds).length===1 ? "0"+seconds : seconds;//Same as mins, but for seconds.
        let remainingTime = minutes+" : "+seconds;

        let videoUrl = this.state.video && this.state.video.name ? "/storage/"+this.state.video.user.name+"'s Videos/"+this.state.video.name : null;

        let video = videoUrl ? <div  className={"videoWrapper"}><video ref={this.videoRef} preload="auto" onTimeUpdate={this.trackTime}>
            <source src={videoUrl} type="video/mp4"/>
            <source src={videoUrl} type="video/ogg"/>
            Your browser does not support the video tag.
            </video>
            <div id="controls">

                <button className="btnV" onClick={this.playPause}><i className={PlayPause}></i></button>
                <div className="time">{remainingTime}</div>
                <input type="range" className="custom-range" id="customRange" name="points1" onChange={this.volume}/>
                <div className="time" onClick={this.fullScreen}><i className="fa fa-expand"></i></div>

            </div>
        </div> : "";

        return (
            <div className="container">
                {video}
            </div>
        );

    }

}

if(document.getElementById('show')){

    ReactDOM.render(<Show/>, document.getElementById('show'));

}
```

**Edit1:** Also autoPlay don't always work when i refresh page ... And shows "Uncaught (in promise) DOMException".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is Chrome's JavaScript console lazy about evaluating arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057440/is-chromes-javascript-console-lazy-about-evaluating-arrays) (DOM node lists are array-like objects)

Answer (score 2):

`componentDidMount()` is invoked immediately after a component is mounted.

Before calling `componentDidMount()`, `render()` will be called to init DOM.

But, in `render()` you did like below:

```
let videoUrl = this.state.video
   && this.state.video.name ? "/storage/"+this.state.video.user.name+"'s Videos/"+this.state.video.name : null;

let video = videoUrl ? <div  className={"videoWrapper"}><video ref={this.videoRef} preload="auto" onTimeUpdate={this.trackTime}>
```

At that first `render()`, `videoUrl` may be false because state.video is not initialized yet.

That means `this.videoRef` won't be initialized in this render funtion.

So it is `null` yet.

Then it is `componentDidMount()` 's turn to run.

At `componentDidMount()` you fetched video and inited `state.video`.

So then the next `render()` will be called. And also `this.videoRef` will be initialized, but not in `componentDidMount()`.

That's why your `console.log` showed `null`.

`this.videoRef` will be initialized like below steps.

1. first render function called.

   this.state.video -> ""

   this.videoRef -> null
2. componentDidMount called

   this.state.video -> something valid.

   this.videoRef -> null
3. another render function as updating this.state.video  called

   this.videoRef -> something valid.

**EDIT:** You can access valid `this.videoRef` when it is initialized at the first time in `componentDidUpdate()`.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  if(prevState.video !== this.state.video) { // this.state.video is updated
     // That is the place where you can access into valid this.videoRef
  }
}
```

Comment: Long story short: Is there a way to get duration and play video unless i play video onClick. And onClick it works. So how to do that?

Comment: Similar behavior as before. Sometimes work some things. For example if i do `this.videoRef.current.play();`, it will be executed, sometimes it will be not. On the other hand, `this.videoRef.current.duration` will always show NaN. Error: "Uncaught (in promise) DOMException".

Comment: Did you call them in `componentDidUpdate()`?

Comment: Yes. I also tried ```componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState){
        if(prevState.video === this.state.video){
            console.log(this.videoRef.current.duration);   
        }
    }``` Which is only activated when i click on play button ... Which isn't very helpful considering that i need duration beforehand.

Comment: @VeljkoStefanovic It is not `===`, it's `!==`.

Comment: If you notice [quote] "I also tried" [/quote] . Emphasize on "also" which means that i tried original example first, then this.